# Oracle trigger to conditionally audit an insert

Tags: oracle

I have a small problem, I am practicing triggers in oracle I have tried to make a trigger that when inserting a record in the table, whose field (numerical value) has a value greater than 20,000 immediately record in a history with the date, the description ( record greater than 2000000), the identifier of the list and which user inserted the record.

This is the table to save the history:

```
  CREATE TABLE RESERVA
  (
  ID INT,
  FECHA DATE,
  USUARIO VARCHAR2(10),
  DESCRIPCION VARCHAR2(20)
  );


y este es el trigger que he intentado hacer pero no me funciona

-----TRIGGER--
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERTELO
AFTER INSERT
ON DATOS
DECLARE

ID int,
Marital_Status varchar2(10),
Gender varchar2 (8),
Income float,
Children int,
Education varchar2(20),
Occupation varchar2(20),
Home_Owner varchar2 (5),
Cars int,
Commute_Distance varchar2(15),
Region varchar2 (13),
Age int,
Purchased_Bike varchar2 (5)
BEGIN
SELECT (@ID=ID, @MARITAL_STATUS=MARITAL_STATUS, @GENDER=GENDER, @INCOME=INCOME, @CHILDREN=CHILDREN, @EDUCATION=EDUCATION, @OCUPPATION=OCCUPATION, @HOME_OWNER=HOME_OWNER, @CARS=CARS, @COMMUTE_DISTANCE=COMMUTE_DISTANCE,@REGION=REGION, @AGE=AGE, @PURCHASED_BIKE=PURCHASED_BIKE) FROM INSERTED
INSERT INTO DATOS VALUES (@ID, @MARITAL_STATUS, @GENDER, @INCOME, @CHILDREN, @EDUCATION, @OCUPPATION, @HOME_OWNER, @CARS, @COMMUTE_DISTANCE,@REGION, @AGE, @PURCHASED_BIKE)

IF @INCOME>2000000
INSERT INTO RESERVA (@ID, SYSDATE, USER, 'EL REGISTRO SUPERO LOS 2 MILLONES')
```

Comment: You would need to translate your question to English to get help here. Or try [stackoverflow en espanol](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Are you using Oracle?  Or SQL Server?  Your trigger seems to be using mostly SQL Server syntax with a small amount of Oracle syntax thrown in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is really an Oracle database, not SQL Server, there is no `inserted` object, variables aren't prefixed with `@`, and there is a `:new` pseudo-record.  You have to specify whether you have a row-level trigger or a statement-level trigger (or a compound trigger composed of row- and statement-level pieces).  Your `insert` statement is missing the `values` clause.  Although not strictly necessary, every `insert` should explicitly list the columns you're inserting into.  Otherwise, you write code that will break as soon as someone adds a new column to the table (and introduce all sorts of bugs when one developer doesn't remember the order of the columns in the table correctly).  And every statement has to end with a semicolon.

So you'd want something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERTELO
  AFTER INSERT ON DATOS
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.INCOME>2000000
  THEN
    INSERT INTO RESERVA( id, fecha, USUARIO, DESCRIPCION )
      VALUES (:new.id, SYSDATE, USER, 'EL REGISTRO SUPERO LOS 2 MILLONES');
  END IF;
END;
```

Google translate believes my explanation translates as

Asumiendo que esto es realmente una base de datos Oracle, no SQL Server, no hay ningún objeto insertado, las variables no tienen el prefijo @ y hay un nuevo pseudo-registro. Debe especificar si tiene un activador de nivel de fila o un activador de nivel de instrucción (o un activador compuesto compuesto por piezas de nivel de instrucción y fila). Su declaración de inserción no tiene la cláusula de valores. Aunque no es estrictamente necesario, cada inserción debe enumerar explícitamente las columnas en las que está insertando. De lo contrario, escribe un código que se romperá tan pronto como alguien agregue una nueva columna a la tabla (e introduzca todo tipo de errores cuando un desarrollador no recuerde el orden de las columnas en la tabla correctamente). Y cada declaración tiene que terminar con un punto y coma.

Entonces querrías algo como

Comment: @melisacarmonasosa - Sorry, included the `is` incorrectly

Comment: @melisacarmonasosa - You declared the column `DESCRIPCION` as a varchar2(20) so it can hold 20 bytes of data.  You are trying to insert a 33 byte string in the trigger.  Either insert a shorter string or increase the size of the column